# How does server know that the client is not longer live?

Tags: go, networking, tcp

I'm trying to understand the way TCP works and what I know so far is that one side can't know if the other is still there if it "random" disconnects. This is why some PING/PONG algorithms or TCP keep-alive are used. I created a simple client-server application where the client connects to the server and after 10 seconds sends a simple message. What confuses me is how the server knows that the client is no longer there in the following two scenarios:

1. I let the program to completely run and finish - in this case the server closes the connection (I don't understand how can server know that the client is no longer there, I didn't indicate anywhere on the client side that I am closing the connection)
2. I shut down the client process before it complete (before it send a message to the server) - in this case the server prints the following message `Error reading: read tcp 127.0.0.1:8080->127.0.0.1:60845: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.` (Again, I don't understand how it can know that the client is no longer there)

What I assume is that the OS (or golang `net` library) is involved here and that it sends additional messages before the TCP connection is really closed or something like that to handle this situation.

Any help is welcome. Below is the complete code I use, so you can run it locally or in the online go playground.

client.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Connect to the server
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting:", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    // Send a message to the server
    message := "Hello from client!"
    time.Sleep(10000 * time.Millisecond)
    conn.Write([]byte(message))

    // Read the response from the server
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    n, err := conn.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading:", err)
        return
    }

    // Print the server's response
    fmt.Printf("Received response from server: %s\n", buffer[:n])
}
```

server.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    // Obtain and print the client's IP address when the connection is established
    clientAddr := conn.RemoteAddr()
    fmt.Printf("Client connected from IP address: %s\n", clientAddr)

    for {
        // Read data from the client
        buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
        n, err := conn.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading:", err)
            return
        }

        // Print received message
        fmt.Printf("Received message from client (%s): %s\n", clientAddr, buffer[:n])

        // Send a response back to the client
        response := "Hello from server!"
        conn.Write([]byte(response))
    }
}

func main() {
    // Start listening on a port
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err)
        return
    }
    defer listener.Close()

    fmt.Println("Server listening on port 8080")

    for {
        // Wait for a connection
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting connection:", err)
            continue
        }

        // Handle the connection in a goroutine
        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}
```

Comment: The client application calls `conn.Close()` when `main()` returns. The call to `conn.Close()` on the client sends a FIN packet to the server.  The call to `conn.Read(buffer)` on the server returns an error in response to receiving that packet.  
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks Cerise. That clarified the first situation, but in second situation `conn.Close()` on the client side does not even occur, so server won't read FIN packet with `conn.Read`. In second situation, I "forcibly" shut down the client process, and the server side somehow knows it and prints an error that the connection has been interrupted.

Comment: @Amadan Yes, that would make sense, but this connection is not a of keepalive type... At least I didn't set it, I don't know if the standard library sets it. But even in that case, it would not be possible to know so quickly whether the peer (client) "left". I literally immediately get a message on the server that the client has left.

Comment: @Amadan Oh thanks, that makes sense. But I have one question then, how can that happen in this situation? Server did not sent any packet, it waits on `conn.Read` and then I shut down client process. It would be clear to me that this happens when the server sends some data (packet), but it just waits in this case.

Comment: The operating system resets the connection if it is still open when the client process exits.

Comment: @user207421 So if some process left open, that is, did not close some TCP connections before it exits (shut down), then the OS will send RST to all these connections and, by that, other sides can also shut down their "part of" connections? That happened in second scenario?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised I was talking about things that I was not too well versed in, so I tested it myself. Toy example, in three separate terminals on the same machine:

Oversight: `sudo tcpdump -tttt -i lo port 8887` (You might need to find out what is your localhost device, maybe `lo0`, using `sudo tcpdump -D`. Watch the Flags field: `.` is ACK, the others should be self-evident.)

Server: `nc -l 8887`

Client: `nc localhost 8887`

- Client: SYN
- Server: SYN ACK
- Client: ACK

Type something in client and press Enter

- Client: PSH ACK
- Server: ACK

Type something in server and press Enter

- Server: PSH ACK
- Client: ACK

a) stop the client, whether by ctrl-c or sigkill:

- Client: FIN ACK
- Server: FIN ACK
- Client: ACK

b) stop the server:

- Server: FIN ACK
- Client: ACK

then stop the client:

- Client: FIN ACK
- Server: RST

This experiment was done on WSL/Ubuntu. I have not compiled your program, but you can test your scenario yourself. One thing that surprised me is that FIN was sent even if I sigkilled the clientside process, indicating that it was the kernel that was responsible for sending FIN if the clientside process terminated with an open port. Also, FIN was not sent when the serverside process was stopped, which made client run into a RST response.

The kernel's implementation of the TCP protocol takes care of this; this is not related to Go at all, except for what happens in `conn.Close()`.

Comment: Yes, based on what you've tested it seems like the kernel does some extra communication. Above in the comments it is also written that the kernel will send RST for all connections that are left open when the process is finished.

Comment: What confuses me is that in case `a` client and server both send FIN ACK, but in `b` case server sends FIN ACK and client just ACK.

Comment: Yeah, it may or may not be specific to the `nc` doing things explicitly (like closing its own socket on serverside) before kernel needs to step in and clean up. But I am just guessing here. This is why I encourage you to do your own experiment (unless you have no root access on your machine, which would be a bummer).

Comment: Of course. Importantly, we eventually came to the conclusion that the kernel closes unnecessary connections and doing its things. How and why is not so important now :). Thank you very much for your help!